# How to check to see if a currency field value is changed in an if statement in salesforce apex?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have an if statement in my code which I check if the picklist of old value is different from the new value but I would also like to include the check if the currency value is changed.
Could anyone please help me as to how would I accomplish that?

```
if (updated_contract.Status__c == 'Completed' && old_status != 'Completed')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite clear on your question. Since, you have tagged your question as trigger, take a look at the following sample code on how to detect change in values inside an apex trigger.

```
for(<SObject> o : Trigger.new) {
    if(o.<field> != Trigger.oldMap.get(o.<Id>).<field>)){
        // Write all your apex logic here
    }
}
```

You will have to update the `<SObject>`, `<field>` etc. with appropriate SObject name and field name. You can use this to detect change in any field type (currency or text or anything else).